# Best approach to create URIs with Sparql (like auto increment)

Tags: sparql, rdf

I am currently writing a service which creates new items (data) by user input. To save these items in a RDF Graph Store (currently using Sesame via Sparql 1.1), I need to add a subject URI to the data. My approach is to use a number that is incremented for each new item. So e.g.:

```
<http://example.org/item/15> dct:title "Example Title" .
<http://example.org/item/16> dct:title "Other Item" .
```

What's the best approach to get an incremented number for new items (like auto incement in MySQL/MongoDB) via Sparql? Or to issue some data and the endpoint autmatically creates a URI by a template (like done for blank nodes). 
But I don't want to use blank nodes as subjects for these items.
Is there a better solution than using an incremented number? My users don't care about the the URI.... and I don't want to handle collisions like created by hashing the data and using the hash as part of the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you maintain a designated counter during updates, then something along these lines will do it,

fisrt insert a counter into your dataset

```
insert data {
    graph <urn:counters> {<urn:Example> <urn:count> 1 }
}
```

then a typical update should looks like:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
delete {
    #remove the old value of the counter
    graph <urn:counters> {<urn:Example> <urn:count> ?old}
} 
insert {
    #update the new value of the counter
    graph <urn:counters> {<urn:Example> <urn:count> ?new}

    # add your new data using the constructed IRI
    GRAPH <http://example.com> {
        ?id dct:title "Example Title" ;
            a <http://example.org/ontology/Example> .
    } .
} where {
    # retrieve the counter
    graph <urn:counters> {<urn:Example> <urn:count> ?old}

    # compute the new value
    bind(?old+1 as ?new)    

    #construct the IRI
    bind(IRI(concat("http://example.org/item/", str(?old))) as ?id)
}
```

Comment: This approach is good, in case it's split up in three requests. One getting the current counter (so it is available in the requesting client), one incrementing the counter and one inserting data with the requested counter. If implemented like in the answer, the client is not able to know which resource has been created and to further process it (as sparql only answers with ~"Success"). This is really a downside of sparql (no Select-Update query support).

Comment: @Roy spliting the update into 3 different simple ones will brake its atomicity. For the main issue, about having some means of identifying the created id after the update, there is always a workaround. For instance, if you maintain a kind of unique external 'request ids' on the client side, you may associate those with the created ids and subsequently using those to find what has been added. You may pass the value of the request id as part of the update, e.g. include in the `where` clause `VALUES ?rq_id { "abscedf" }` and add a statement like `?id <urn:ref> ?rq_id`.

Comment: What you describe is a workaround, that's true. But it doesn't seem to fit the current web architecture paradigms. E.g. it's not usable for the UUID answer and it's not usable in case there are multiple clients with acccess to the store - like by scaling up a store client (service). The alternative of having a third party id creation service is like breaking a butterfly on a wheel...as well as keeping track of all subjects of a class and to diff these on insert.

Comment: @Roy the earlier draft of Sparql 1.1 came up almost 10 ago, so it is somewhat unfeasible to expect that it should be up-to-date with the modern web architecures. In case you have a fixed schema, one way to deal with the issue is to either build a lightweight GraphQL service interacting with the RDF store which fits your particular requrements and so to expose it to your clients or wait until some third party (vendor or community) provide a sound and usable solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the class of your items is `http://example.org/ontology/Example`, the query becomes the following. Note: items must be inserted one by one, as only one new URI is computed at each transaction.

```
PREFIX dct: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
INSERT {
    GRAPH <http://example.com> {
        ?id dct:title "Example Title" ;
            a <http://example.org/ontology/Example> .
    } .
} WHERE {
    SELECT ?id WHERE {
        {
            SELECT (count(*) AS ?c) WHERE {
                GRAPH <http://example.com> { ?s a <http://example.org/ontology/Example> }
            }
        }
        BIND(IRI(CONCAT("http://example.org/item/", STR(?c))) AS ?id)
    }
}
```

(Tested with GraphDB 8.4.0 using RDF4J 2.2.2)

Comment: That's quite clever. It will not work if resources are deleted as well as created.

Comment: Also likely at risk of collisions if executing transactions below SERIALIZABLE isolation level.

Comment: This approach is clever, indeed. If implemented like in the answer, the client has no knowledge about which resource has been created (as sparql only answers with ~"Success"). Unfortunately there is no Select-Update query support in sparql, requiring to split this request into two requests.

Answer (score 2):

You said you are open to other options than an auto-incremented number. One good alternative is to use [UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

If you don't care at all what the URI looks like, you can use the [`UUID`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-uuid) function:

```
INSERT {
    ?uri dct:title "Example Title"
}
WHERE {
    BIND (UUID() AS ?uri)
}
```

This will generate URIs like `<urn:uuid:b9302fb5-642e-4d3b-af19-29a8f6d894c9>`.

If you'd rather have HTTP URIs in your own namespace, you can use [`strUUID`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-struuid):

```
INSERT {
    ?uri dct:title "Example Title"
}
WHERE {
    BIND (IRI(CONCAT("http://example.org/item/", strUUID())) AS ?uri)
}
```

This will generate URIs like `http://example.org/item/73cd4307-8a99-4691-a608-b5bda64fb6c1`.

UUIDs are pretty good. Collision risk is negligible. The functions are part of the SPARQL standard. The only downside really is that they are long and ugly.

Comment: As a hack to reduce the length, you could use a hash on top. E.g. `BIND (IRI(CONCAT("http://example.org/item/", MD5(STRUUID()))) as ?uri)`. Not really any prettier, but the resulting string will be shorter. Risk of collision is still pretty much negligible.

Comment: MD5 hashes with a 128-bit value have long been considered broken from a collision perspective, so UUIDv4 with a 122-bit random component is even more broken.  And operationally UUID collisions are being encountered.  The risk of collision is not negligible with a production-scale deployment; a new standard practice (e.g., urn:sha256:jLtOocmz9InHDCL1W4l7OLjX-NATWpt_7uKJLAgGX8w) is needed.